# How can I know that object is lambda?

Tags: c++, lambda, delegates

I'm trying to create a delegate. I'm passing a function pointers that should be called later. The pointers that is already added should be ignored. For global/static and for member function pointers it's trivial - I'm just comparing addresses. But lambda doesn't have compare operator. Right now I have something like this (templated function):

```
make_delegate(void(*)(int)); // for global function
make_delegate(obj, void(MyClass::*)(int)); // for member function
```

And I'd like to keep this interface also for lambdas, i.e. i can write:

```
make_lambda_delegate([](int){});
```

but I don't want. I want to have single `make_delegate` for everything. What is the best way to do it?

Comment: you don't have to know. A stateless lambda can be implicitly converted to a pointer-to-(non-member)-function.

Comment: Easy: don't have the rule that "if you add something twice, I ignore it the second time".  That seems like it solves problems, but it actually creates them.

Comment: @The Paramagnetic Croissant Yes! Exactly. Thanks.